# How to use a video logo for the DearPyGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, video, dearpygui

I'm new to Python GUI's and am currently trying to build an app with DearPy. I was wondering if it's possible to use an mp4 formatted logo (animated logo) instead of the png logo's it would usually accept. For example:

```
with window("Appi", width= 520, height=677):
    print("GUI is running")
    set_window_pos("Appi", 0, 0)
    add_drawing("logo", width=520, height=290)

draw_image("logo", "random.png", [0,240])
```

My question is: would it be possible to change the add_drawing to an add video and then the draw_image to allow me to insert an mp4 instead of a png? I've tried to look through the documentation but haven't found guidance for this yet.

Or is there an alternative package I should be using (i.e. tkinter)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used tkinter for this and it worked perfectly fine:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import os
import time

try:
    import imageio
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    os.system('pip install imageio')
    import imageio

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Settings:
video_name = 'your_video_path_here.extension' #This is your video file path
video_fps = 60

video_fps = video_fps * 1.2 # because loading the frames might take some time

try:
    video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)
except:
    os.system('pip install imageio-ffmpeg')
    video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):
    '''Streams a video to a image label
    label: the label used to show the image
    '''
    for frame in video.iter_data():
        # render a frame
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(frame))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

        time.sleep(1/video_fps) # wait

# GUI

root = tk.Tk()

my_label = tk.Label(root)
my_label.pack()

thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
thread.daemon = 1
thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Edit: Thanks <3

Comment: I even put some lines in there that make sure you have installed it using pip correctly :)

Comment: Thanks @nsde for such an informative answer!

Answer (score 0):

Videos are in DearPyGui currently not supported

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.